# create an array of char arrays

Tags: c, arrays

If I have 5 arrays of char like this

```
char a[6] = "";
char b[6] = "";
char c[6] = "";
char d[6] = "";
char e[6] = "";
```

and I also have this part of code which gets some tokens with strtok and put them in a,b,c,d,e

```
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL)
 {
    fputs(buff,stdout);
    FILE *ft = fopen("/home/pi/Desktop/data.txt","a+");
    struct tm *tp;
    time_t t;
    char s[80];
    t = time(NULL);
    tp = localtime(&t);
    strftime(s, 80, "%d/%m/%Y  %H:%M:%S", tp);
    char *pos = strchr(buff,'N');
    if (pos)
    {
         ptr = strtok(buff, "Nodo_,=:V()");
         i = 0;
       while (ptr != NULL)
         {
          if (i == 0)
             strcat(a, ptr); 
          if (i == 2)
             strcat(b, ptr); 
          if (i == 4)
             strcat(c, ptr); 
          if (i == 6)
             strcat(d, ptr); 
          if (i == 8)
             strcat(e, ptr); 
          ptr = strtok(NULL, "Nodo_,=:V()");
          i++;
         }
      printf("Results: %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", a, b, c, d, e);
```

my question is how can I create a new array (example TABLE) with these 5 values like

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

and secondly is there any way to convert this array to

```
a b c d e
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: perhaps you are talking about array of char pointers??

Comment: I do not understand the question either? Is it about memory layout? Or about how are the values printed to the screen?

Comment: Ok I want to save these values a,b,c,d,e in an array vertically. The other question is for my education how to convert an array lets say 5x1 to 1x5.

Comment: The language does not allow such a conversion of the dimensions as you want, but most compilers will not complain when you cast the pointer value to the pointer type you want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you want, but here's a shot:

```
char (*TABLE_5x1[5][1])[6] = {
    { &a },
    { &b },
    { &c },
    { &d },
    { &e }
};

char (*TABLE_1x5[1][5])[6] = {
    { &a, &b, &c, &d, &e }
};
```

Comment: If I have also &f &j I will do it like this char (*TABLE_1x5[1][7])[8]= {{ &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f, &j }};

Comment: @dali1985: As long as each of them are `char[8]`, and you should probably also rename the variable name to match the new size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One last question, in your way, if I want the &e to change it with 0 how can I declare it?Like this '0'?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you would do `TABLE_1x5[0][4] = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

define `char* TABLE[5]`. and then you can put a,b,c...into this array as its elements.